# Select date and jquery event occurs automatically

Tags: jquery, date

I want to call a jquery when i select a date. I was using `$().change(function{})` for the `select` tags but its not working for the date. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#ChangeMonth").????(function()
{
})
```

**html:**

```
<input id="ChangeMonth" class="datepicker" style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 18px; margin-top:47px; margin-left: 14px; width: 160px; height: 24px;" />
```

Comment: What is `ChangeMonth`?

Comment: selecting a date using datepicker does not fire any event... you need to use the `onSelect` or `onClose` properties to register the desired handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
       onSelect: function(){
            alert('Date selected');
            // your code
       }
    });
});
```

Read [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) property, as changing the value using datepicker does not fire any event

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#ChangeMonth').datepicker({
        onClose: function () {
            console.log('onClose', this, arguments)
        },
        onSelect: function () {
            console.log('onSelect', this, arguments)
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z6wMD/)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#ChangeMonth').datepicker({
        onClose: function () {
            alert("on Close");
        },
        onSelect: function () {
            alert("on Select");
        }
    });
});
```

//It works for onClose, onSelect.